# Video doesn't go fullscreen in Ionic

Tags: android, video, ionic-framework, fullscreen

I'm using [vzaar](https://vzaar.com/) video host to implement a video using `<iframe>` tag in my Android mobile app built with Ionic framework.

Everything works fine except fullscreen option. Video doesn't go fullscreen when I press the fullscreen button in the vzaar player.

**Info:**

- fullscreen works fine when I test the mobile app in Chrome on my computer
- I also tested vzaar player using Chrome on Android device and it works
- Vzaar support says Android may be blocking the video, but it works in Chrome on Android device
- the only problem is in the mobile app so I guess something in Ionic framework is preventing it going fullsreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add project crosswalk plugin

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

Console command

```
ionic platform remove android or ios (your uses platform)
ionic platform add android or ios (your uses platform)
```

[Click me for crosswalk docs](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html)